# How to sort NSArray alphabetical order?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsarray

I have an array and I listed data in it like following.

```
[directoryContent sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]
```

but the output is,

```
<__NSArrayI 0x16739870>(
 bedsheet0.jpg,
 bedsheet1.jpg,
 bedsheet10.jpg,
 bedsheet11.jpg,
 bedsheet2.jpg,
 bedsheet3.jpg,
 bedsheet4.jpg,
 bedsheet5.jpg,
 bedsheet6.jpg,
 bedsheet7.jpg,
 bedsheet8.jpg,
 bedsheet9.jpg
```

)

But I need to sort this list like following,

```
<__NSArrayI 0x16739870>(
 bedsheet0.jpg,
 bedsheet1.jpg,
 bedsheet2.jpg,
 bedsheet3.jpg,
 bedsheet4.jpg,
 bedsheet5.jpg,
 bedsheet6.jpg,
 bedsheet7.jpg,
 bedsheet8.jpg,
 bedsheet9.jpg
 bedsheet10.jpg,
 bedsheet11.jpg,
```

)

How can I do this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: It can be duplicated.  But how can I find it by topic `I have an NSArray on NSString's, but some of the strings are only numbers. How do I sort numerically properly?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [NSNumericSearch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/NSNumericSearch) to search the numeric value in string like this:-

```
NSArray * products = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Product1",@"Product10",@"Product2",@"Product3",@"Product4",@"Product5",@"Product6",@"Product7",@"Product8",@"Product9", nil];

products = [products sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [(NSString *)obj1 compare:(NSString *)obj2 options:NSNumericSearch];
}];

NSLog(@"products : %@", products);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using sort descriptor.

> NSArray *unsortedArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"12", @"4",
>   @"89", @"5", @"2", @"10", @"1", nil]; NSArray *sortedArray =
>   [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(NSString *str1, NSString
>   *str2) {
>       return [str1 compare:str2 options:NSNumericSearch]; }];